# Calculating the cosine similarity

Tags: information-retrieval

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the cosine similarity of these two vectors:

`A:(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)`

`B:(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)`

From what I understand, I need to multiply `A` by `B` and then divide it by the length of `A*B`.

The first part I understand, but how do I know what the length is?

- `A` is a document with 11 words
- `B` is a query with 7 words

Does the length refer to the number of words? Or do I have to 'normalize' the vectors? I'm unsure because, from what I understood, the cosine already normalizes the vector.

Any helps and hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you!! I think I figured it out. I came to the cos of 0.40824829046386302363116512559835. Could you maybe confirm if this is the correct one? Thank you for your time to clarify this for me :)

Comment: scipy has a built in methods for doing this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/55717

Answer (score 0):

Vector operations are defined on elements of a vector space (the dimensionality of which needs to be predefined).

So, even though we loosely use the terminology `sparse vector`, it's nothing but an efficient way to represent a `dense vector`...

For your example involving text vectors - both a document and a query are nothing but dense vectors (the dimensionality is the size of the entire vocabulary).

The first step is to convert a document and a query to a dense vector representation.

If D=`<the cat sat on the mat>` and Q=`<cat on mat>`,

then the vocabulary (set of unique words) is {cat, mat, on, sat, the}

Our toy vector space is hence of dimensionality 5. Each vector is hence represented by 5 numbers, where the value represents presence/absence or count of the corresponding term.

`vec(D) = (1, 1, 1, 1, 2)` - because cat occurs once, the occurs twice in D and so on.

Similarly, `vec(Q) = (1, 1, 1, 0, 0)` - note the 0's corresponding to the terms that are not present, e.g. the term `the`.

Cosine similarity is the normalized inner product.

The numerator is simply \sum_i a_i * b_i, which for this example is
`1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1 + 1.0 + 2.0 = 3`

What about the lengths? For finding the length (specifically L2 norm) of a vector simply compute its inner product with itself and then take a square root.

`Len(D) = sqrt(1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1 + 2.2) = 2sqrt(2)`

`Len(Q) = sqrt(1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1 + 0.0 + 0.0) = sqrt(3)`

Hence `cosine-sim = 3/(2sqrt(2)*sqrt(3))`

Finally, for your example,

```
A:(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) and B:(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1),

A.B = 1
Len(A) = sqrt(A.A) = sqrt(2)
Len(B) = sqrt(A.A) = sqrt(3)

cosine-sim = 1/sqrt(6) = 0.4082
```